# Mosaic to New Raster outputs whole numbers instead of decimals

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, merge, mosaic

I just ran the ArcMap Mosaic to New Raster tool to merge 5 rasters of pH levels in different farms. These individual rasters have values that are decimals. When I run the tool, the output is in whole numbers. Why is this occurring and how do I change it? Could it be an environment setting, a tool property setting, or a data property setting? Nothing looks even remotely out of place.
     [image]

Comment: What specific type of raster is the mosaic? Right click raster layer > Source > Pixel Type & Pixel Depth

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the `Pixel Type (optional)` to `32_Bit_Float` or `64_Bit`, if you want decimals:

> 32_BIT_FLOAT—A 32-bit data type supporting decimals
>
> 64_BIT—A 64-bit data type supporting decimals.

[image]

By default it is `8_BIT_UNSIGNED`, which means unsigned integer.

Comment: Ah, that was totally the problem. The rasters being merged were all 32 bit float. I just assumed the raster output file would be the same as the inputs.

Comment: @jcbridwe Glad it solved the problem. Actually the downside of using `32_Bit_Float` is that the file size will also increase.